# Musedo Metronome and Tuner MT-40W Tuning Key doubt

Tags: guitar, beginner, metronomes, tuner

I got hold of a guitar from a friend who moved recently and gave away some of his stuff he didn't need. This is an accoustic guitar .

I figured I could learn how to play it from the internet :p

It included a digital tuner and metronome by musedo ( MT-40W). I was looking up tutorials to tune my guitar and could not understand which tuning key to select on the tuner machine to test my strings on. It has 4 options ( C, F, B♭, E♭ ) .

I don't really understand music theory so please explain which option is used for tuning a guitar? C or F or B♭ or E♭ ? The Musedo website says the tuner has two tuning modes - Chromatic and wind instruments. Which tuning key option on the tuner should i select for tuning an accoustic guitar ?

Answer (score 1):

Attach the clip to the head of the guitar, play each string and the tuner will tell what note it's sounding. Fat to thin, aim for E A D G B and E, but be careful you're in the right octave for each string.

The 'C' option may make the difference, as it's not transpositional, so switch to that over the others.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which option… C, F, B♭, E♭

Comment: @Tetsujin - I suspect those refer to the keys for wind instruments. When the clip is attached, it becomes a chromatic tuner and will respond to the guitar strings.I

Comment: I'd still always set it to C just in case… cos why couldn't you use a clip on a wind instrument?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the options are intended for wind instruments where the written pitch of the note is different from the sounding pitch.

That does not apply to guitar, so you want the "C" option.